# Which jQuery method of creating a canvas of a certain size has the best performance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

What I'd like to do is create a 15 by 15 pixel sized canvas with jQuery and I am looking for an elegant way to do it.

I currently create a canvas with jQuery like this:

```
var canvasNode = $('<canvas />', {
  style:'display:block',
  width:15,
});

// canvasNode[0].width=15;
canvasNode[0].height=15;
```

An oddity is that the `width:15` in that has no effect while the currently commented out line below does what I'd like to do. I also tried `style:'display:block;width:15px;'` but while that displays the canvas at 15px width the canvas itself stays at its large default size so its just being scaled so that's not what I seek.

Comment: Premature optimization.

Comment: You shouldn't worry about performance unless you have an actual performance issue. However I believe that passing the width in the first example has a nasty side-effect: it will set the element's `style.width`, which will scale the canvas contents too, not just the canvas.

Comment: Looking it up and asking how are two different things.

Comment: IMO the "best practice" is to use what is more clear, the most readable and maintainable code. You should worry about performance in resource-intensive procedures, but not with something as trivial as creating a DOM element and assigning a property to it (unless you are doing that many, many times in a loop). Also, if you're really worried about performance, forget jQuery, as it's an extra layer of code that will necessarily cost something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that sending in an object with a width property will set the css width to 15px (basically just scaling the canvas), the canvas will still be created with the default number of pixels in width if no width attribute is specified, which is usually 300 pixels.

Just set the width and height attributes:

```
$('<canvas />', {
  style:'display:block'
}).attr('width', 15).attr('height', 15);
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried the width() and height() methods which just affected the css width and height again. attr() obviously was what I was looking for. Is attr({width:15,height:15}) better than two chained calls? The function does take simple objects like that...

Comment: @C.O. it should be, but you can only know for sure by testing.

Comment: The difference is neglible for few attributes. By chaining, you avoid creating an object (which costs) but need to do several attr() calls (which costs). I think it's safe to say it pretty much evens out. Unless you create thousands of canvases I would not worry about it, use the style you find most readable.

Comment: Shouldn't you rather use `.prop()` for that?

Answer (score 2):

In case you are really worried about performance, this is the fastest way (untested, but I'm sure it is):

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 15;
canvas.height = 15;
```

That is, no jQuery at all.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I had in the first place but since what I write is used in a jQuery context I figured I could as well use jQuery hence the question.

Comment: If you later need to manipulate it with jQuery, you can just use $(canvas).